# Android : API version of downloaded source code

Tags: android, eclipse, api

How can I find out which API version was used to write open-source library I downloaded? How do I find out which API is it compatible with?

Comment: Did you check the manifest for min and target sdk versions?

Comment: a i checked .but its minsdk version showing 10 and terget 14. it was developed for 1.6 donut

Comment: And what if a manifest file did,t uses this...???

Answer (score 2):

GO to manifest file and check this tag :

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

It will show you min , target and max sdk version

Comment: yea i checked...and we should set our AVD with respect to this version to run the code ?

Comment: u can take any AVD but it should be greater or same version that mentioned in android:minSdkVersion="8". For ex. You cannot run app below sdk version 8 for above. while you can run it on 10, 11 till 16.